# MVVMCross-Android dynamic fragment inside fragment and manage navigation stack per fragment

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am currently working on MVVMCross Xamarin Android project. So far I have achieved normal navigation and bottom bar navigation. I want to open dynamic fragments inside each bottom bar tabs. e.g I have bottom bars menus Recent, Favorite and NearBy. Clicking on each tab it create fragments. Inside each fragment I want to provide facility to dynamically create fragments on click.

I want to achieve here is, it should keep stack of navigation tab wise. Let say I created 5,3,4 fragments respectively for Recent, Favorite and Nearby and currently I am on favorite tab and clicking on back should first navigate back to all 3 tabs. Like wise it should follow navigation for other tabs.

Exact same feature and functionality available in this github link
[https://github.com/ncapdevi/FragNav][1]. This is one is for Android but I need advice how can I achieve same functionality with Xamarin, MVVMCross and C#.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your link is dead,and then i think you need to understand the back stack of fragments and show hidden features to implement that.[FragmentTransaction](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction#FragmentTransaction())

general train of thought, you have  `RecentFragment`, `FavoriteFragment` and `NearByFragment` three root fragments,
when you click the relative tab ,you can use **show** and **hide** method of fragment like
this :

```
 FragmentTransaction fTransaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            hideAllFragment(fTransaction);
            //judge which tab is clicked
            switch (tab.Id)
            {
                case Recent:                
                    if (recentFragment== null)
                    {
                        recentFragment= new RecentFragment ();
                        fTransaction.Add(Resource.Id.ly_content, recentFragment);
                    }
                    else{fTransaction.Show(recentFragment);}break;
                case Favorite:
                    if (favoriteFragment== null)
                    {
                        favoriteFragment= new FavoriteFragment();
                        fTransaction.Add(Resource.Id.ly_content, favoriteFragment);
                    }
                    else{fTransaction.Show(favoriteFragment);}
                    break;
                case NearBy:
                    if (nearByFragment== null)
                    {
                        nearByFragment= new NearByFragment();
                        fTransaction.Add(Resource.Id.ly_content, nearByFragment);
                    }else{fTransaction.Show(nearByFragment);}break;
            }
            fTransaction.Commit();
```

and then in each root fragment to implement the back stack use **addToBackStack** :

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = FragmentManager;
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.Replace(containerViewId,fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.AddToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.Commit();
```

at last you could try to encapsulating a controller

Comment: Thank you for looking in to this Leo Zhu. I will go through your answer and update you. Please check link https://github.com/ncapdevi/FragNav.

Comment: Hi Leo, your idea seems fine but to achieve exact functionality what I did is I converted complete github.com/ncapdevi/FragNav controller code in C#. It took lot of efforts but finally it works as expected.  Still I have to check how to include MVVM Cross view models.

Comment: @JanakDarji Did you find a solution for the ViewModels in Mvx?